# Laravel belongsToMany vs creating intermediate table model

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have belongsToMany relation in my project:

`public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class,'order_products','order_id','product_id')
            ->withPivot('amount')
            ->withTimestamps();
    }`

hence I don't have any model for intermediate table order_products. At this point, everything is okey but I have questions with this relation.

1. belongsToMany relation causes me to write a query like that:

   `$cart=Auth::user()->orders()
               ->where('status', 0)
               ->firstOrFail()
               ->products()
               ->newPivotStatement()
               ->join('products', 'order_products.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
               ->select(DB::raw('products.*,(products.price * order_products.amount) as newPrice'), 'order_products.amount')
               ->get();`
   Does it cause performance issue? So should I use a model for order_products table? (Note that, I have more than one queries like that).
2. Should I use query builder for  getting a result as in the first question or should I use collection methods to get this result (like sum(), each() methods..) to achieve performance.
3. In general, which one is high performance: Try to get refined result with an sql query or get a result and just refine with php/laravel?

System: laravel 5.4 / php 7.1 / mysql 5.7

Sorry for my bad english. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's break down what happens when you query database by using Laravel.

1. Use Eloquent/Database query builder to generate SQL.
2. Send the generated SQL to database and execute.
3. Get the result data from database.
4. Hydrate Eloquent model instances (if you use Eloquent) or plain PHP objects (if you use query builder) from data.

For most cases, the 2nd step is the bottleneck, you should check the generated SQL to see if you can improve it.

For your questions:

1. Dose it cause performance issue? So should I use a model for order_products table?

   The performance depends on your database and the generated SQL. Use a model for order_products maybe helpful to simplify your code, but it doesn't have a directly impact on performance.
2. Should I use query builder for getting a result as in the first question or should I use collection methods to get this result (like sum(), each() methods..) to achieve performance.

   If you can't use query builder to generate a more performant SQL statement then there's no need to switch. Using collection normally means you need to fetch data from database to PHP memory and then calc the result in PHP, I believe it will be slower if you have a large dataset to query.
3. In general, which one is high performance: Try to get refined result with an sql query or get a result and just refine with php/laravel?

   To get better performance, you should focus on SQL statement. Once you get a high performance SQL, you can build it with Eloquent/Query builder or what ever you feel convenient, or you can pass the sql to \DB::select() to get the result. Eloquent and database query builder have performance costs on building sql statement, but the costs could be ignored compare to SQL execution in most cases.

Comment: thank you for your answer. But 3rd one need to be clerify. For instane  lets think about these two code snippet DB::all()->sortBy('price');  DB::orderBy('price','asc')->get(); , which one is more performance? As you see, the first one gets all data and after that sorts it with laravel collection's methods. But the second one gets datas sorted. It seems the second one does more work on sql and the first one does more work on php/laravel. So which one should be choosen?

Comment: If the database can use index to [optimize the order by clause](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/order-by-optimization.html), then the performance of database sorting is better. If the dataset is very large, you should consider if PHP has enough memory to handle that data. If both PHP and database have enough memory, you could refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3620992/2042600). In general, database sorting has better performance. I think you need to make a test against the data you have to get an exact answer.