# sortBy of collection and orderBy of Eloquent, which one is faster in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a `users` table and I have associated `User` model for it. Now to get all the user from that table ordered by `updated_at` I can follow two following ways:

**1. Using Eloquent(DB): let's say MySQL**

`User::orderBy('updated_at')->get();`

**2. Using collection method(PHP)**

`User::get()->sortBy('updated_at');`

Between this tow ways, which one is better/faster? and why?

Comment: greatly dependent on indices

Comment: Does it mean if I don't do indexing then PHP will execute faster?

Comment: Nope, I side with Mathieu, DB is almost always faster, but an index is going to make it a night and day difference

Comment: So, you are saying query execution time with index and without index has a great difference which I already know. and my question here is not about query vs query, it's query vs php. In that case you said DB is almost always faster. Why **almost always** not **always**? Is there any case when php is faster? Besides, Can you tell me why DB is almost always faster?

Comment: Cause its literally build and optimized to do that.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3619701/is-php-sort-better-than-mysql-order-by

Comment: Why don't you test it yourself?  It should be general knowledge that a database is going to be better at sorting than almost any programming language's sorting methods but sometimes it is much more convenient or efficient to sort at the collection level, especially when you already have the data in a collection from another method.  Your question lacks specifics and research, for 2 users, it really doesn't matter, for 2000 users 1 will obviously be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, using your database driver is much faster than using the collection because it is his purpose to fetch and order Datas :)

Laravel Collection is just arrays on steroid, but with a database driver, you can even increase performance by adding indexes to your columns.

Comment: I also think so. The reason you have mentioned is not clear enough. Collection is also have the purpose of containing and manipulating data.